# Spring Framework does not required sever. Is it true?

Tags: spring

I read in [spring tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-tutorial) in advantages section point no. 3. Spring Framework does not required server . Is it true ?

how can we run web application without any server?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You can run a standalone spring application.

Your main class will be the entrypoint, you can load the bean definitions using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. E.g.

```
public static void main() {
   ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ctx.xml");
   YourService service = ctx.getBean(YourService.class)
   service.doSomething();
}
```

Then everything in `doSomething()` can use dependency injection.

---

**Update:** Since you seem to need to run a webapp without a web server - you can't. You need a servlet container (which would be a 'web server' here). What you can do is use an embedded web server like jetty or tomcat-embedded and launch the process from a standalone app.

If by "web server" you mean a remote physical (or virtual machine) - you don't need it - you can install tomcat locally on your machine and run the application.

Comment: Thanks 4 ur answer but i know that,i wanna know how can we run web application without server.

Answer (score 5):

Spring is not specific to web applications, this is why it can be used as a standalone.
You can see how to use it with Bozho's Answer.

What I understand from your comment is that you want to create web application without server. Please fix (edit) your question if you want to get the answer you expect.

Anyway, **this is not possible**. You need a **web server** (software) for such a purpose.

Nevertheless if by 'server', you mean the hardware and not the software, then it is different. You can run a web server on your own computer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a Java **web** application you need at least a Servlet Container. Applications written with the Springframework will do so too. But there are some ways to "embed" the Servlet Container ("server") into your application so that if feels like running the application without a server.

There is a new Spring project [Spring Boot](http://blog.springsource.org/2013/08/06/spring-boot-simplifying-spring-for-everyone/) that tries to simplify this. Have a look at the [git repository](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-boot/blob/master/README.md) and the *Embedded Tomcat* and *Embedded Jetty* samples or watch the litte [demonstration video](http://youtu.be/dPDZHiucDCw) of Eberhard Wolff.